# Error en servicio MongoDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, aplicación-web, iis, mongod

Al momento de procesar consultas, navegar en mi plataforma o insertando informacion desde mi plataforma web, el servicio de mongodb empieza a subir en cuanto el porcentaje del uso de cpu y memoria. Pero cuando lllega al 25% o mas, como muestro, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ya no es posible trabajar con las plataformas, todas las plataformas se ponen muy lentas, tardan demasiado en cargar.
 Uso IIS, las plataformas estan ASP.net y mi servidor tiene 2TB y 16 GB de ram.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o comentario.

Comment: Vas a tener que usar docker

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow, me puedes ampliar un poco sobre el comentario de usar docker?